# Two dimensional array value combine one of each array with other java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In two dimensional array length I could not mention statical like this " object32[(0)] " I need to iterate with loop concept

```
    var object32 = [["fgd","dsg","dsgds"],["dgfs","ewrw","zsf"],["mmm","ewrw","zsf"]];
    object_len_value=object32.length;
     object_len=object32[0].length;
      for($i=0;$i<object_len;$i++){
    console.log(object32[(0)][$i]+"="+object32[1][$i]+"="+object32[2][$i]);

    }
```

I have Two dimensional array value and I need get result like this

OutPut :

```
 fgd = dgfs = mmm
 dsg = ewrw = ewrw
 dsgds= zsf  = zsf
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? your code outputs the desired result.

Comment: He is testing our attention.

Comment: what kind of output you want ? because your code ouput is similair to what you want

Comment: I need not mention it like this  object32[(0)] .I need iterate with loop do not need to mention array of  0 value.

Comment: Do you want a generic solution that not only works with `object32`, but any object that you pass to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Update your question and I'm sure you will have the answer.

Comment: object32[(0)] I mention array['0'] is there is way I do not mention like this  and iterate get the result like this

Comment: Please Understood with question .make it needful status

Comment: Below I got a answer that is the way I need to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.
You can iterate through the array and keep on adding the to the result array based on the item index.

```js
var object32 = [["fgd","dsg","dsgds"],["dgfs","ewrw","zsf"],["mmm","ewrw","zsf"]];

let results = []
object32.map(obj => {
  obj.map((o, i) => {
    results[i] =  results[i] ? results[i] + ' = '+ o : o;
  })
})

results.forEach(r => console.log(r));
```

Comment: Thanks lot ..it is correct

Comment: Glad that I could help